# Will java delete the extra variable in polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
public abstract class car{
   protected String carA,carB,carC;
}

public class car_A{
   car_A(){
       carA = "carA";
   }
}

public class car_B{
   car_B(){
       carB = "carB";
   }
}

public class car_C{
   car_C(){
       carC = "carC";
   }
}

public class test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      Car[] a = new Car[3];
      Car[0] = new carA();//Will carB & carC be delete?
      Car[1] = new carB();//Will carA & carC be delete?
      Car[2] = new carC();//Will carA & carB be delete?
   }
}
```

Will garbage collection delete the other String in the object?

Extra question: Is it possible to have unique variable declaration in a subclass that allows me to use polymorphism?

Comment: Java has garbage collection. If an object is no longer reachable, it is eligible for collection. You usually don't have to think about disposal of memory.

Comment: what do you think garbage collections is doing? deleting the variables?

Comment: Thanks guys.Are there any way for me to have unique variable declare in a subclass and it also accept me to use polymorphism?

Comment: All of your subclasses will have a carA, carB, and carC field on them.  They will be garbage collected when they are no longer reachable.  As for your extra question, yes...

Comment: You code will not complier cause car_A, car_B & car_C have to extend car class. Car[0] it needs to be a[0]. As for your answer to your question not it will not be garbage collected it would just be set to null. As it is part of the object all though you you are not using it now you may choose to use it later.

Comment: @LawrenceMcAlpin, Please help me, explain it briefly, Thanks a lot.

Comment: It also won't compile because `Car[0]` is trying to treat a type as an array...

Comment: In the future, please use real code, not kind-of, sort-of code. You're asking questions about key core Java concepts, and we need to know unambiguously what you're asking and what the code is supposed to represent, and real compilable code will help.

Comment: This question smells of the XY problem to me.  Even an abstract class should _mean_ something.  In your example, every `car` instance has fields named `carA`, `carB`, and `carC`.  What is the meaning in that?  What is the _real_ problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

```
new carA();//Will carB & carC be delete?
```

"Delete" in what way?  You have an object reference, and that object contains three variables:

```
protected String carA,carB,carC;
```

One of those variables has been assigned a value:

```
carA = "carA";
```

The other two have not, so they are `null`.  (Which means there's nothing to "delete" anyway.)  But all three of those variables exist.  The object holds a reference to them, and your code holds a reference to that object.

Once nothing holds a reference to that object, it will be eligible for garbage collection and is effectively "deleted".

> Are there any way for me to have unique variable declare in a subclass and it also accept me to use polymorphism?

It's really not clear what you're asking there, and I suspect that's coming from a misunderstanding of what polymorphism is.  Each instance of the object is separate and distinct and is composed of the entire hierarchy of classes which defines the type.  If you want your child objects to have only one variable, then create only one variable:

```
public abstract class car{
   protected String carValue;
}

public class car_A extends car{
   car_A(){
       carValue = "carA";
   }
}

// etc.
```

Each instance will have exactly one variable, and that variable will consistently have the same name.  Each type assigns its own default value to that variable, and all other code within the class (child class or parent class)  would just reference that one variable for any operation that needs it.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really helpful to me.

Comment: This is incomplete in a way that is misleading: *Once nothing holds a reference to that object, it will be eligible for garbage collection and is effectively "deleted".* An object is eligible when it's no longer *reachable*, even if there are other non-reachable objects that hold a reference to it. In particular, it is *not* necessary to null out all the reference fields in objects that are going out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

> Will garbage collection delete the other String in the object?

I assume that you mean ... will something eliminate the variables?

The answer to that is No.  All three variables will exist in all three subclasses.

It doesn't make sense to ask about whether something will delete the strings. The string *objects* you are referring to don't exist: they are never created.  The fields that you don't initialize in your example subclasses will contain `null` rather than `String` objects.  Besides, objects are only ever deleted when the GC (or the compiler if "escape analysis" is enabled) deduces that they have become unreachable.

---

> Extra question: Are there any way for me to have unique variable declare in a subclass and it also accept me to use polymorphism?

If you expose the variables, then No.

If you make them private, and provide access using getters and setters, then there is a hacky way to do it:

```
public abstract class X {
   public abstract String getA();
   public abstract String getB();
}

public class Y extends X {
   private String a;

   public String getA() { 
      return a; 
   }

   public String getB() { 
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("no b"); 
   }

   // or ...
   public String getB() { 
      return null;
   }
}
```

However this is not recommended, because these hacks are violating the principle of substitutability.

Answer (score 0):

- We talk about **Polymorphism** when there is **Inheritance** so you should change your code like  `public class CarA extends Car{` to make inheritance.
- When there is an Inheritance between `Car` class and `CarA` class, then SubClass `CarA` will inherit all proprieties from SuperClass `Car` (`String carA,carB,carC`), and when you initialize carA like that `carA = "carA";`in `CarA` Constructor the result is (`carA` will have `"carA"`,`carB` will have `null`, `carC` will have `null`  )

So ther Answer of your Question **Will java delete the extra variable in polymorphism?** is NO